# How to use jQuery to show a form for a specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to show and hide the edit options for each post. Here is the jQuery that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".post-menu").click(function () {
        $(".menu-options ul").toggle();
    });
    $(".edit-option").click(function () {
        $("#edit-post").show();
        $(".menu-options ul").toggle();
    });
    $("#never-mind").click(function () {
        $("#edit-post").hide();
    });
})
```

**Slight introduction about code:** the post-menu is the div which handles the show hide events, edit-options is the `<ul>` that has to popup containing edit and delete as `<li>` in it, the #edit-post is the div for a textarea, submit button (which uses ajax jquery; no need to have a form), and #never-mind is a button to close it.

The div code is:

```
<div class="post-menu">
    <div style="width: 20px; height: 8px;" >Options</div>
    <div class="menu-options">
        <ul>
            <li class="edit-option">Edit</li>
            <li class="delete-option">Delete</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div> // I missed this while writing the question, sorry for that!
    <div style="display: none;" id="edit-post">
        <textarea id="new-post-message">@row.Message</textarea>
        <br>
        <button onclick="updatepost(@row.PostId)">Save</button>
        <button id="never-mind">Never mind</button>
        <div class="error-post"></div>
    </div>
```

**Desired Behavior:** Show the options panel only for the selected post.

**Current Behavior:** The problem is that it unhides the option panel for every post when I just want to show the options panel the selected post.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your event handler, `this` is the element which was the target of the event. Start there, then use jQuery traversal functions to find the elements you want to act on.

Comment: The description isn't clear to me.  Also, the post-menu div never closes in the above example, so the bound click event will be fired no matter where someone clicks.

Comment: It seems you have the same structure for every div, if that's the case it should be changed as IDs are supposed to be unique...

Comment: True, I am using a `foreach() loop` to get posts of users!

Comment: My response was late, but it may be helpful. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's my response.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LKjg4/)

You have a few issues here (which is why it took a while to post this).

1. If you are using a loop to output user posts, then the IDs will be duplicated. That is a no-no. Please use classes, or add a unique identifier to each ID. See the ID added to each post-menu div.
2. Your jQuery says to toggle the UL element when the user clicks on the 'post-menu' div, but to also toggle the same element if they click on the 'edit' item, which is inside the 'post-menu' div. In other words, both events will fire when user clicks the EDIT button, and the UL will toggle twice. Use e.stopPropagation() to avoid that.
3. Since you do not reliably know the *unique* ID of elements near the clicked item, you should use jQuery DOM traversal selectors, like `next()` or `parent()`. See my example.
4. You can see how I alerted the found element ID as I worked to locate the correct element. I left in those tests just to show you how to do that.

REVISED HTML:

```
<div class="post-menu" id="PostMenu1">
    <div style="width: 20px; height: 8px;" id="OptionsDiv">Options</div>
    <div class="menu-options">
        <ul id="myUL" class="myUL">
            <li class="edit-option">Edit</li>
            <li class="delete-option">Delete</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="edit-post">
    <textarea id="new-post-message">@row.Message1</textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="savebutt" onclick="updatepost(@row.PostId)">Save</button>
    <button class="never-mind">Never mind</button>
    <div class="error-post"></div>
</div>
<!-- ---------------------------------------------------------- -->
<div class="post-menu" id="PostMenu2">
    <div style="width: 20px; height: 8px;">Options</div>
    <div class="menu-options">
        <ul>
            <li class="edit-option">Edit</li>
            <li class="delete-option">Delete</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" class="edit-post">
    <textarea id="new-post-message">@row.Message2</textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="updatepost(@row.PostId)">Save</button>
    <button class="never-mind">Never mind</button>
    <div class="error-post"></div>
</div>
```

REVISED JQUERY:

```
$(".post-menu").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".menu-options ul").toggle();
});
$(".edit-option").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find(".edit-post").show();
    //var x = $(this).closest('div').parent().next().attr('class');
    //alert(x);

    //$(this).parent().parent().find('ul').toggle();
    $(this).closest('div').parent().next().toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    //var x = $(this).parent().parent().find('ul').attr('class');
    //alert(x);
});
$(".never-mind").click(function () {
    //var x = $(this).closest('div').attr('class');
    //alert(x);
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
});
$('.delete-option').click(function(e) {
    var x = $(this).closest('div').parent().attr('id');
    alert('Deleting DIV with ID: ' + x);
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I was trying to tell that I need the `ID` by that the post; lets make it clear, every post has a unique ID so I was hoping I should use that, I was not able to create the jQuery. Thanks to you. You might be late to party, but you are correct for the party!

Comment: The `ID` are not needed at all. Using simple classes and properly targeting the elements will make the HTML cleaner and the logic more consistent and simpler

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan You'll end up having multiple `id="new-post-message"` if you think that is fine, well, I'm away from this party :)

Comment: No brother, @RokoC.Buljan, I was talking about the ID of post, as I am populating the divs via database, the database is having a unique ID of that post, so was trying to use that ID as the ID of the container div or span.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have multiple divs with the class `post-menu` & you need its corresponding menu options to toggle based on the context. This is what you need.

```
$(".post-menu").click(function (e) {
    $(this).find(".menu-options ul").toggle();
});
```

EDIT: as @Roko mentioned.. if you don't want to bubble the event propagation..

use `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Almost correct, note the OP about the duplicate `ID` might give this A a go. Additzionally any click that will bubble to the parent element will toggle the menu, so be careful

Comment: So is that all? Or do I need some kind of ID too? As the `menu-options ul` is not nested in the `.post-menu`. Its just outside this div, but is nested inside `.post-viewer`. So I think I should use, `$(".post-viewer").find("menu-options ul").toggle();`, right?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - In your question `menu-options' is nested inside 'post-menu'.. if thats not the case.. use its appropriate outer class.(I'm assuming you have just 1 menu-options div.. otherwise you might have to use closest div)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the question, I just editted it; the div was ended above the menu-options! So I placed it here, as people were saying the div is unclosed and that's the issue. So I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

`<div style="width: 20px; height: 8px;" />Options</div>` is not the way we should close DIV elements (note the `/>`)

Avoid the use of `ID` if you want to handle multiple elements
use the right selectors for the job like `$(this).next()` etc... and you're done.

Comment: Hehe my bad, actually this was not a div, I just want to show a simple code. The real code that I am having contains 5 if else blocks, to check the user is logged in, then to check whether is current user then to check whether he needs to be here not. And also it was an Image, whose name had to pass 3 folders and a long `Guid.NewGuid()` name so I skipped and missed this, but you're correct!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan look, I don't need to teach you how to use animations or toggles, instead of `ID` replace them with `class` names, target them correctly inside their parent elements as descendants or as target-next elements, not just like global class element collections, and you're done.

Comment: The issue is not the `ID` or `CLASS`, neither do I want to learn animations or toggles. All that I want is that I am using foreach loop, that creates 10 divs similar to each other! Thats why I might consider using the `ID` of post, not the `id` of that div. So that I have a unique div to do the toggle for. This was the point that you are not able to get or maybe I was not able to make you fully understand.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan all I want to say is that I don't need to show you the code to help you achieve your goal! :) nothing mean. And believe me, you cannot have duplicate ID all over the place. It's illegal in the DOM.

Comment: yeah, its illegal! But the ID I am talking about was the unique number from database, not `<div id="">` this id. Sorry, I was not able to make it up for you to understand :( My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Would be useful for a jfiddle with multiple entries, but I think you just need to add $(this)

Also you might need to turn your menu options into a ID rather than a class

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".post-menu").click(function () {
    $(this).(".menu-options ul").toggle();
});
$(".edit-option").click(function () {
    $(this).("#edit-post").show();
    $(this).(".menu-options ul").toggle();
});
$("#never-mind").click(function () {
    $(this).("#edit-post").hide();
});
})
```

Comment: As I posted above, I think I provide you with the link of that comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343243/how-to-use-jquery-to-show-a-form-for-a-specific-div/18343413?noredirect=1#comment26926727_18343391